# PySide: Add images to tooltips

Tags: python, html, image, tooltip, pyside

I'm building a tool that lists files in a directory.  When you hover over each file it shows a tooltip displaying the date and who made the file.  I'd also like an image to accompany this data.

Is it possible to insert an image into a tooltip?  For each item in the QTreeView I'd like a specific image and text to popup.  If it can't be done with  tooltips are there other alternatives?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

def get_parent():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( long( ptr ), QtGui.QWidget )   

############################################        
''' Classes '''
############################################
class Main_Window( QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( Main_Window, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()
        self.create_connections()
        self.get_contents()

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_gui( self ):
        self.tv_model=MyModel()
        self.tv_file_list = File_List( self )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_layout( self ):
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout( self )
        self.main_layout.addWidget( self.tv_file_list )
        self.setLayout( self.main_layout )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_contents(self):
        self.tv_model.clear()
        self.tv_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name","date"])
        contents=["path1","path2"]
        for path in contents:
            date = self.get_date(path)
            self.add_file(path,date)
        self.tv_file_list.setColumnWidth(0, 150)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_file(self, name, date):
        name = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
        name.setToolTip(name.text())
        name.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        date = QtGui.QStandardItem(date)
        self.tv_model.appendRow([name, date])

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_date(self, path):
        return "a date"

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_connections( self ):
        self.tv_file_list.clicked.connect( self.on_click )

    # slots --------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_click(self, item ):
        index = self.tv_file_list.selectedIndexes()[0]
        item = self.tv_model.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        print item

############################################
class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable 
        return flag

############################################
class File_List( QtGui.QTreeView ):
    ''' Create the file filters '''
    def __init__( self, mainUIWindow, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( File_List, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setModel(mainUIWindow.tv_model)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setColumnWidth(0,500)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setStyleSheet("QToolTip { color: rgb(170,170,170); background-color: rgb(20,20,20); border: 1px rgb(20,20,20); }")


############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # workaround for a bug in maya
    try:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    tree_view_ui = Main_Window()
    tree_view_ui.show()

    try:
        tree_view_ui.show()
    except:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
```

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to ekhumoro for the quick and easy solution! 
Here's the updated code and a [link](https://plot.ly/online-graphing/tutorials/source-links-text-and-html-in-graphs/) to some HTML basics that helped me format the tooltip:

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
    import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

```
def get_parent():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( long( ptr ), QtGui.QWidget )   

############################################        
''' Classes '''
############################################
class Main_Window( QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( Main_Window, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()
        self.create_connections()
        self.get_contents()

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_gui( self ):
        self.tv_model=MyModel()
        self.tv_file_list = File_List( self )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_layout( self ):
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout( self )
        self.main_layout.addWidget( self.tv_file_list )
        self.setLayout( self.main_layout )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_contents(self):
        self.tv_model.clear()
        self.tv_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name","date"])
        contents=["path1","path2"]
        for path in contents:
            date = self.get_date(path)
            self.add_file(path,date)
        self.tv_file_list.setColumnWidth(0, 150)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_file(self, name, date):
        name = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
        user_text = "Me"
        image_path = "C:/windows/temp/image_01.png"
        name.setToolTip('<b>{0}</b><br><img src="{1}">'.format(user_text, image_path))
        name.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        date = QtGui.QStandardItem(date)
        self.tv_model.appendRow([name, date])

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_date(self, path):
        return "a date"

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_connections( self ):
        self.tv_file_list.clicked.connect( self.on_click )

    # slots --------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_click(self, item ):
        index = self.tv_file_list.selectedIndexes()[0]
        item = self.tv_model.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        print item

############################################
class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable 
        return flag

############################################
class File_List( QtGui.QTreeView ):
    ''' Create the file filters '''
    def __init__( self, mainUIWindow, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( File_List, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setModel(mainUIWindow.tv_model)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setColumnWidth(0,500)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setStyleSheet("QToolTip { color: rgb(170,170,170); background-color: rgb(20,20,20); border: 1px rgb(20,20,20); }")


############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # workaround for a bug in maya
    try:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    tree_view_ui = Main_Window()
    tree_view_ui.show()

    try:
        tree_view_ui.show()
    except:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltips accept rich-text, which means you can use any markup that is part of the [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html). This includes an `img` tag, so all you need is something like:

```
    item.setToolTip('<b>%s</b><br><img src="%s">' % (filename, iconpath))
```